# liberty openstack ubuntu install guide fails to ping router

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I followed the install guide for liberty launching instances on private networks (option 2)  but I am unable to ping the virtual router

```
    neutron router-port-list router
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name | mac_address       | fixed_ips                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 6384c950-ab12-4514-b582-78a80fcd267a |      | fa:16:3e:4b:d4:00 | {"subnet_id": "57db368e-9dad-42be-a3eb-58399266acf4", "ip_address": "192.107.88.61"} |
| b66d679f-3d6b-4784-a802-94eb827d3167 |      | fa:16:3e:49:79:85 | {"subnet_id": "da685b38-b88b-4a35-9ebb-37c37ea322c3", "ip_address": "192.168.10.1"}  |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

my public network is 192.107.88.0/25
and the private one is 192.168.10.0/24

```
    ping 192.107.88.61
PING 192.107.88.61 (192.107.88.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.107.88.61 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13104ms
```

while ping versus other hosts in public network works well.
Please let ne know.
Angelinux

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run **ifconfig** in the router? Check that both interfaces are well configured.

Assuming your router id is *router* as in your question, the command `ip netns exec router command` lets you execute commands in the router.

Try: `ip netns exec router ifconfig`

You should also try to test the router connectivity: `ip netns exec router ping 8.8.8.8`